# SQLSTATE[42000]: There can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: php, laravel

I have a proble running below code in laravel .I wanted to create a testimonial table by migration but it thinks more than one primary key is in `up()`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTestimonialsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('testimonials', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->text('comment');
            $table->integer('created_by',10);
            $table->integer('last_updated_by',10);
            $table->string('position',50);
            $table->string('address',100);
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
    }
}
```

The above code shows error saying more than one autoincrenet columns ..or bla bla ...
sample of error

```
$ php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key (
SQL: create table `testimonials` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(100) not null, `comment` text not null, `created_by` int not null auto_increment primary
 key, `last_updated_by` int not null auto_increment primary key, `position` varchar(50) not null, `address` varchar(100) not null, `image` varchar(191) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `
updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php: 664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php : 458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php : 458

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: error seems clear, whats the issue?

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid I even removed  $table->primary('id'); but the same error.. Please see about last_updated_by and created_by column in error sample above

Comment: Remove second parameter from `$table->integer('created_by'` and `$table->integer('last_updated_by'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table `testimonials` (
`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
`name` varchar(100) not null, 
`comment` text not null, 
`created_by` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
`last_updated_by` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
`position` varchar(50) not null, 
`address` varchar(100) not null,
`image` varchar(191) not null, 
`created_at` timestamp null, 
`updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
```

Check your generated query here more than one column is primary key so that's the error So You just need to remove

```
$table->integer('created_by',10);
$table->integer('last_updated_by',10);
```

lines and Use

```
$table->integer('created_by');
$table->integer('last_updated_by');
```

Or if want them as `primary key` then go for `composite primary key`.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('testimonials', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->text('comment');
            $table->integer('created_by');
            $table->integer('last_updated_by');
            $table->string('position',50);
            $table->string('address',100);
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE testimonials ADD CONSTRAINT check_created_by CHECK (created_by<=10)');
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE testimonials ADD CONSTRAINT check_last_updated_by CHECK (last_updated_by<=10)');
    }
```

Comment: Well ther is no problem running directly SQL in phpMyadmin but, It doesnot work in laravel even while removing $table->primary('id'); line

Comment: Try now i edited my answer remove 10 from `$table->integer('created_by',10);` and `$table->integer('last_updated_by',10);`

Comment: Thanks, removing 10 kinda works but can't I use to limit integer as `$table->integer('last_updated_by',10);` as i uses as `$table->string('name',50);`

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to the method **integer** is the culprit as it somehow says to mark that field as primary key.
In your case the `$table->increments('id');` will set that field as **Incrementing ID (primary key) using a "UNSIGNED INTEGER" equivalent**. So remove primary key setting method and remove the second param from integer method.

Hope this clarifies the doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

try this: it will help you. Just copy and paste this code to your migration file.

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('testimonials', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->text('comment');
            $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('last_updated_by')->unsigned();  
            $table->string('position',50);
            $table->string('address',100);
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why did you add calls to `unsigned`?

Comment: that mean only positive value will be inserted on this column.

Comment: Has this been a requirement from the OP? You cannot tell him "use this" and change the logic on your own

Comment: It only stores positive values